# Applying a match within a function for a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table that contains for each ID, the X and Y coordinates and a number of columns that contain neighbouring ID's. The neighbouring ID's refer to other observations/rows in this DT.

The goal here is to set certain ID's to NA, if their distance is too large. To do this, I have to apply my distance function to the X and Y coordinates of the matching ID in the DT.

```
#the update function
update_columns <- function(dt, columns_to_update) {
   for (col in columns_to_update) {
      dt[, (col) := ifelse(chebyshev_distance(x,y, dt.nearest_neighbours[match.SD, c("x", "y"), on="id"]) > 10, NA, dt[[col]])]
   }
   return(dt.nearest_neighbours)
}

#the chebyshev distance function
chebyshev_distance <- function(x1, y1, data) {
   pmax(abs(x1-data$x), abs(y1-data$y))
}


#I created a mock data.table for reproducing the problem:

dt.nearest_neighbours <- data.table(
  id = c(1,2,3,4), #the ID
  x = c(10, 20, 30, 40), #the X coordinate of the ID
  y = c(5, 10,25,5), #the Y coordinate of the ID
  V1 = c(2,3,2,1), #a neighbour of the ID -> the numbers in the V columns refer to other ID's in this dt
  V2 = c(4,1,4,2), #a second neighbour of the ID
  V3 = c(3,1,1,3) #third neighbour of the ID
)
```

This current code gives the following error:

'match.SD is not found in calling scope and it is not a column name either. When the first argument inside DT[...] is a single symbol (e.g., DT[var]), data.table looks for var in calling scope'.

It seems the match is not done properly. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved with the following code:

```
update_columns <- function(dt, columns_to_update) {
  for (col in columns_to_update) {
    dt[, (col) := ifelse(chebyshev_distance(x, y, dt[.(id = get(col)), .(id, x, y), on = "id"]) > 10, NA, dt[[col]])]
  }
  return(dt)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, preferring to use joins and completely vectorized (no "frames") distance calc.

```r
chebyshev_distance2 <- function(x1, y1, x2, y2) pmax(abs(x1-x2), abs(y1-y2))
update_columns2 <- function(DT, columns, limit = 10) {
  if (is.numeric(columns)) columns <- names(DT)[columns]
  stopifnot(
    "'x2' and 'y2' are used internally, they must not be in 'DT'" =
      !any(c("x2", "y2") %in% names(DT)),
    "'columns' must be length 1 or more, non-NA, and character/integer" =
      length(columns) > 0 && !anyNA(columns) && (is.character(columns) || is.numeric(columns)),
    "'limit' must be length-1, non-NA, and numeric/integer" =
      !anyNA(limit) && length(limit) == 1 && is.numeric(limit)
  )
  on.exit(suppressWarnings(DT[, c("x2", "y2") := NULL]), add = TRUE)
  for (col in columns) {
    na <- DT[[col]][1][NA]
    DT[DT, c("x2", "y2") := .(i.x, i.y), on = paste(col, "== id")]
    DT[, (col) := replace(get(col), chebyshev_distance2(x, y, x2, y2) > limit, NA)]
  }
  DT
}
```

Demo:

```r
DT
#       id     x     y    V1    V2    V3
#    <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
# 1:     1    10     5     2     4     3
# 2:     2    20    10     3     1     1
# 3:     3    30    25     2     4     1
# 4:     4    40     5     1     2     3
update_columns2(DT, c("V1","V2","V3"))[]
#       id     x     y    V1    V2    V3
#    <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
# 1:     1    10     5     2    NA    NA
# 2:     2    20    10    NA     1     1
# 3:     3    30    25    NA    NA    NA
# 4:     4    40     5    NA    NA    NA
```

This produces the same results as you and performs *slightly faster* with this (small?) dataset.

```r
update_columns(DT, c("V1","V2","V3"))[]
#       id     x     y    V1    V2    V3
#    <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
# 1:     1    10     5     2    NA    NA
# 2:     2    20    10    NA     1     1
# 3:     3    30    25    NA    NA    NA
# 4:     4    40     5    NA    NA    NA

bench::mark(
  TvCasteren = update_columns(DT, c("V1","V2","V3"))[],
  r2evans = update_columns2(DT, c("V1","V2","V3"))[]
)
# # A tibble: 2 × 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result       memory time             gc                
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>       <list> <list>           <list>            
# 1 TvCasteren   2.53ms   2.81ms      356.        NA     8.58   166     4      466ms <dt [4 × 6]> <NULL> <bench_tm [170]> <tibble [170 × 3]>
# 2 r2evans      2.15ms   2.33ms      430.        NA     6.29   205     3      477ms <dt [4 × 6]> <NULL> <bench_tm [208]> <tibble [208 × 3]>
```

---

Data

```r
DT <- data.table::as.data.table(structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4), x = c(10, 20, 30, 40), y = c(5, 10, 25, 5), V1 = c(2, 3, 2, 1), V2 = c(4, 1, 4, 2), V3 = c(3, 1, 1, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
```